# Can't drag ImageView in linearLayout using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

When I use a linear layout I am unable to graphically move any elements around in the WYSIWYG editor. If I set them to relative I can, but I the reasoning doesn't make sense to me. After reading up I am under the impression linear is somewhat like absolute positioning. Shouldn't dragging objects be possible?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:background="#400080"
    tools:context="com.x.EntranceActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mobile_full_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can't visually move elements inside `LinearLayout`.
LinearLayout can hold all elements in vertical orientation or horizontal orientation, so there is no need for dragging elements somewhere else.
But you can set `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` attribures for elements to position them in right way as you want.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> A Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single row. The direction of the row can be set by calling setOrientation().

You can tweak things like gravity, padding, and weight, but there is no way to set absolute positions. As such, dragging them around in the WYSIWYG editor is disabled.